# What would be best manner to push viewcontroller from right using UInavigationcontroller?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, popviewcontroller

I was wondering how to push a viewcontroller using the UINavigationtionController but from **left** side.
For now I know two ways

1) Using UIAnimations...

2) Using pop the viewcontroller rather than pushing!

Well its seems like when application has complex stacks then above methods does not seems to be appropriate methods to implement.

If you guys know any other way; please share your knowledge

Regards Zahur

Let me try to dig deep about this matter.

Let say a window based application has spiltview controller & Master view has tabview controller and each tabs has a uinavigation controller;
aka content view controller; 
it becomes prety complex to manage the stacks.

Comment: How did you do the pop thing, why it does not work? I think this is the post probable answer since the your view hirachy is complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, pushing onto a UINavigationtionController pushes a viewController on from the right to the left.

Popping pops the viewController off from the left to the right.

This is behaviour users expect.

If you try to change this, I feel that you will be violating Apple' Human User Interface Guidelines and confuse your users. So I say you shouldn't do this.

What is your data/stack structure like that makes you think this is a good idea? I ask as there's maybe a better way.